# How to specify zone when using gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud-cli

When I wanna transfer files to a instance but this instance is not in my default zone of gcloud-cli, how to specify a zone?

Answer (score 0):

use --zone. For example,

```
gcloud --zone us-east1-d
```

Comment: A more detailed example: gcloud compute instances create example-instance --zone us-central1-f , is provided in the [gcloud compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#set_values_on_each_request) online document.